# Integrating ShareKit 2.0 in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Can any one tell me that what I'm doing wrong while integrating the new SDK Sharekit 2.0 in my App?

I downloaded the sdk from the "[git://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit"](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit), and following the instruction for installation and integration from the https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki.

At the end when I build the program so it failed and give no error or exception, when I drag the ShareKit classes from the Sharekit.xcodeproj then it give two errors of duplication (`SHKDefaultConfiguration.h`), what to do with this and how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try removing and then again adding them?
May be,at time of adding,something might went wrong.

Comment: first i have added according to the instruction? after folowing the complete instruction what to do with the sharekit.xcodeproj file? because when i complete the wiki instruction then i added customConfiguration file but which give error "ShkDefualtConfiguration.h not found"

Comment: @Pfitz yes i have imported SHKDefaultConfiguration.h in my customConfiguration file where i want to give keys for facebook, twitter and other but give me this error?

Answer (score 0):

You must not import the ShareKit files in your project, just import (drag and drop) the ShareKit Xcode project file.

But you need a reference to the ShareKit .h files in your project, so you have to add the path of the .h in your build settings.

Add in your target "Header Search Paths" :

```
$(SRCROOT)/[The/Relative/Path/Of/ShareKit]/Classes/**
```

And

```
$(SRCROOT)/[The/Relative/Path/Of/ShareKit]/Submodules/**
```

For example if you put ShareKit on a directory "ShareKit" at the same level of your project directory, you add :

```
$(SRCROOT)/../ShareKit/Classes/**
```

And

```
$(SRCROOT)/../ShareKit/Submodules/**
```

Comment: i have downloaded it in the folder where myProject Classes file and myproject.xcodeproj exist. so what path i should use for this, while i have already added /../shareKit/submodules/** in Header searchPath.

Comment: Can you post the exact absolute path of myproject.xcodeproj and shareKit directory? submodules is maybe not enough, you should add also Classes/**